# SQL Row Number with Grouping

Tags: sql, grouping, row-number

I am not sure whether this can be done. I want to group the data based on company with consecutive date.  Below is the desired result I am attempting in SQL.

| **EmpNo** | **Company** | **StartDt** | **EndDt** | **Desired Result** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0003 | C01 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 0003 | C02 | 2021-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-15 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 0003 | C02 | 2021-01-16 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-20 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 0003 | C01 | 2021-01-21 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-31 00:00:00.000 | 3 |

Comment: We need more details to be able to assist, please see here for pointers on creating good question:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to detect when a company changes and then a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when company = prev_company then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by empno order by startdt) as desired_result
from (select t.*,
             lag(company) over (partition by empno order by startdt) as prev_company
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```html
SELECT * FROM `<your-table>`
GROUP BY `Company`
ORDER BY `StartDt` DESC
```